# Foreman Cannot Start Nginx, But I Can Start it Manually. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, nginx, foreman

I am currently running [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) on staging (Ubuntu) and once I get it working will switch to using upstart.

My Procfile.staging looks like this:

```
nginx: sudo service nginx start
unicorn: bundle exec unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.rb
redis: bundle exec redis-server
sidekiq: bundle exec sidekiq -v -C ./config/sidekiq.yml
```

I can successfully start nginx using:

```
$ sudo service nginx start
```

However when I run `$ foreman start`, whilst the other three processes start successfully, nginx does not:

```
11:15:46 nginx.1   | started with pid 15966
11:15:46 unicorn.1 | started with pid 15968
11:15:46 redis.1   | started with pid 15971
11:15:46 sidekiq.1 | started with pid 15974
11:15:46 nginx.1   | Starting nginx: nginx.
11:15:46 nginx.1   | exited with code 0
11:15:46 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
11:15:46 unicorn.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
11:15:46 redis.1   | terminated by SIGTERM
11:15:46 sidekiq.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

**So why isn't nginx starting when started by Foreman?**

Comment: Check out your nginx logs, "exited with code 0" could mean a lot of things. Usually the logs can be found at /var/log/nginx

Comment: @TanelSuurhans Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately there are two logs, but both /var/log/nginx/access.log and /var/log/nginx/error.log are empty.

Comment: What happens if you do `$ sudo foreman start` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The is a problem in your Procfile.

The `nginx` command can't use `sudo` inside `foreman`, because it will `always ask for a password` and then it will fail. That's why you are not starting `nginx` and the logs are empty.

If you really need to use sudo inside a procfile you could use something like this:

```
sudo_app: echo "sudo_password" | sudo -S app_command
nginx: echo "sudo_password" | sudo -S service nginx start
```

which I really don't recommend. Other option is to call `sudo foreman start`

For more information check out this [issue on github](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/14), it is precisely what you want to solve.

Keep me posted if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to add sudo access without a password for your local user to allow managing this service.  This can be a big security hole, but if you whitelist what commands can be run you dramatically reduce the risk.  I recommend adding no-password sudoers entry for the services command and anything else you want to script:

/etc/sudoers:

```
your_user_name       ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

Another option if you're not comfortable with this would be to run nginx directly, not through the service manager:

```
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx -c /path/to/nginx.conf
```